# Error testing Puppet / TheForeman

Tags: bash, dns, puppet, ubuntu-14.04

I am writing a [bash script](http://pastebin.com/LkakDjEX) for the public (and myself) to set up a **Puppet / TheForeman** server real quick on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server, which is based on this [HOWTO](http://www.theforeman.org/manuals/1.6/quickstart_guide.html). I have done nothing on the part of DNS.

```
ping $(hostname -f)

PING foreman.test.local (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from foreman.test.local (192.168.1.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from foreman.test.local (192.168.1.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from foreman.test.local (192.168.1.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from foreman.test.local (192.168.1.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
```

After running the bash script I expect the test to give good results, but instead I get an error message:

```
sudo puppet agent --test

Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to find foreman.test.local via exec: Execution of '/etc/puppet/node.rb foreman.test.local' returned 1: 
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed when searching for node foreman.test.local: Failed to find foreman.test.local via exec: Execution of '/etc/puppet/node.rb foreman.test.local' returned 1: 
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: looks to me like `foreman` doesn't what who `foreman.test.local` is

Comment: `s/what/know/` sorry

Comment: Can you run `/etc/puppet/node.rb foreman.test.local` and paste the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [read](http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.6/quickstart_guide.html) it seems like an option to choose

> sudo apt-get install puppetmaster -y

but that is the problem and doesn't work in this case.

So in this case it should be

> wget apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb

and

> dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb

instead!